# Need help with inconsistent loading iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, google-chrome, flask

I'm trying to include a Facebook share `iframe` on a site that's served using Flask and Apache. The `iframe` loads inconsistently however and I am at a loss for possible explanations. Here is what I have observed:

- The iframe loads correctly in Firefox and Safari but not Chrome 10.0 dev, on Mac
- In Chrome, the iframe never loads correctly when I load the entire page
- If I strip half of the elements from the page, the iframe loads correctly maybe three times out of ten - doesn't matter which half I remove.
- If I strip all of the elements from the page, the iframe loads correctly every time.

The inconsistent behavior makes me think there's some sort of race going on, but I don't understand what the problem would be, or why it would only appear in Chrome. Anyway, I appreciate your help. You can view the site [here](http://goodmorningpomona.com). Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they key is in this statement:

> If I strip half of the elements from
>   the page, the iframe loads correctly
>   maybe three times out of ten - doesn't
>   matter which half I remove.

I'd dump the output to a text file and would run tidy(1) or xmllint(1) over the response to see if you have a mis-matched HTML tag. Chances are Chrome is not handling the error correctly, but Firefox and Safari are able to recover.